# ponydocs install step 5

Tags: php, wamp, mediawiki, parse-error

I am currently installing Ponydocs at my company. I have made it through step 4 on the install but on step 5 I am getting this error when I try and go to the site.

> **Parse error**: syntax error, unexpected `$ponyDocsProductsList` (`T_VARIABLE`) in 
>   `C:\wamp\www\LocalSettings.php` on line `179`

Here is the code that it is talking about

```
################# PONYDOCS START #################
    #Ponydocs Logo
        $wgLogo = "/extensions/PonyDocs/images/pony.png";
    #Implicit group for all visitors, remove access beyond reading
        $wgGroupPermissions['*']['createaccount'] = false;
        $wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit'] = false;
        $wgGroupPermissions['*']['createpage'] = false;
        $wgGroupPermissions['*']['upload'] = false;
        $wgGroupPermissions['*']['reupload'] = false;
        $wgGroupPermissions['*']['reupload-shared'] = false;
        $wgGroupPermissions['*']['writeapi'] = false;
        $wgGroupPermissions['*']['createtalk'] = false;
        $wgGroupPermissions['*']['read'] = true;
    #User is logged-in. Ensure that they still can't edit.
        $wgGroupPermissions['user']['read'] = true;
        $wgGroupPermissions['user']['createtalk'] = false;
        $wgGroupPermissions['user']['upload'] = false;
        $wgGroupPermissions['user']['reupload'] = false;
        $wgGroupPermissions['user']['reupload-shared'] = false;
        $wgGroupPermissions['user']['edit'] = false;
        $wgGroupPermissions['user']['move'] = false;
        $wgGroupPermissions['user']['minoredit'] = false;
        $wgGroupPermissions['user']['createpage'] = false;
        $wgGroupPermissions['user']['writeapi'] = false;
        $wgGroupPermissions['user']['move-subpages'] = false;
        $wgGroupPermissions['user']['move-rootuserpages'] = false;
        $wgGroupPermissions['user']['purge'] = false;
        $wgGroupPermissions['user']['sendemail'] = false;
        $wgGroupPermissions['user']['writeapi'] = false;
    #Our "in charge" group.
        $wgGroupPermissions['bureaucrat']['userrights'] = true;
    #Custom permission to branch ALL topics for a version.
        $wgGroupPermissions['bureaucrat']['branchall'] = true;
    #Implicit group for accounts that pass $wgAutoConfirmAge
        $wgGroupPermissions['autoconfirmed']['autoconfirmed'] = true;
    #Implicit group for accounts with confirmed email addresses This has 
    #little use when email address confirmation is off  
        $wgGroupPermissions['emailconfirmed']['emailconfirmed'] = true;
    #Users with bot privilege can have their edits hidden from various log pages by default
        $wgGroupPermissions['bot']['bot'] = true;
        $wgGroupPermissions['bot']['autoconfirmed'] = true;
        $wgGroupPermissions['bot']['nominornewtalk'] = true;
        $wgGroupPermissions['bot']['autopatrol'] = true;

    $wgArticlePath = '/$1';

    #Ponydocs environment configuration.  update to your specific install
            define('PONYDOCS_PRODUCT_LOGO_URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['interanetsrvr'] . '/extensions/PonyDocs/images/pony.png');
        define('PONYDOCS_PDF_COPYRIGHT_MESSAGE', 'Copyright Splunk, Inc. All Rights Reserved');
        define('PONYDOCS_ENABLE_BRANCHINHERIT_EMAIL', true)
    #NOTE: this *must* match what is in Documentation:Products.This will be fixed in later versions
    $ponyDocsProductsList = array("Foo");
    define('PONYDOCS_DEFAULT_PRODUCT', "Foo");  

    include_once($IP . "/extensions/PonyDocs/PonyDocsExtension.php");
#################  PONYDOCS END #################
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
define('PONYDOCS_ENABLE_BRANCHINHERIT_EMAIL', true);
//                     This semi-colon is missing ^^^
$ponyDocsProductsList = array("Foo");
```

Comment: Okay so that took care of that answer. Now I am getting a view different errors. http://tinypic.com/r/2z66o7t/6